# Complex Analysis Problems

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose the product $z_1z_2$ of two complex numbers is a nonzero real constant. Show that $z_2$ = $k\overline{z}_1$, where $k$ is a real number.

Hint: $z_2$=$k$ conjugate of $z_1$

Comment: Hello! Welcome to MSE! Since you are new, you may not know, but it is expected usually to give what you have already tried and did, so people can help you.

Comment: @Netchaiev Thank You for ur welcome to me, i'm new and i need help for this question even if u don't i will be thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z_1 = a + bi, z_2 = c + di$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.

So $z_1z_2 = (ac-bd) + i(bc+ad)$.

If the result is purely real, then $bc = -ad$. Either $b = d = 0$ in which case $z_1$ and $z_2$ are both real and the result immediately follows or $\frac db = - \frac ca = -k$ (say) where $k$ is a real number.

So $d = -kb$ and $c = ka$, giving $z_2 = k(a - bi) = k\bar{z_1}$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

If $0 \ne z_1z_2=c \in \mathbb R$, then $z_2= \frac{c}{z_1}=\frac{c \overline{z_1}}{z_1\overline{z_1}}=\frac{c \overline{z_1}}{|z_1|^2}=k \overline{z_1}$, where $k= \frac{c }{|z_1|^2}$.

Comment: You just prove it greatly..Thanks